# Opening a new scene in java FX

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I have two FXML files and one Controller.

I have posted the code in which i have tried to  create a second stage (and failed).

Error message is:

```
javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane cannot be cast to javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader
```

How do I fix it?

```
@FXML private Scene trial_scene;
@FXML public  Stage m;     

@FXML public void click(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    m = new Stage();
    openWindow(); 
}

@FXML private void openWindow() throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader root =FXMLLoader.load(
        SampleController.class.getResource(
            "settings.fxml"
        )
    );
    m.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
    m.setTitle("My modal window");
    m.setScene(trial_scene);
    m.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static method FXMLLoader.load returns the root node (and so the objet hierarchy) defined in the .fxml file. In your case it seems to be an AnchorPane.

Your fist line should be

```
AnchorPane root = FXMLLoader.load(SampleController.class.getResource("settings.fxml"));
```

Use this object to construct your new scene, for example

```
Scene trial_scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300, Color.BLACK);
```

Then pass this scene to your new stage

```
m.setScene(trial_scene);
```

Comment: @jewelsea: Thanks for your blogs. I can see your name in every Java FX pages . keep rocking !!